# Upload file in angular / web API

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I created a function that add a new user with Angular/WebAPI ,  so in angular i send the object like this :

```
 AddUser(person : person):Observable<person>
  {
    return this.http.post<person>(this.baseUrl,person);
  }
```

and in WebAPI i got the data :

```
[HttpPost]
  public async Task<ActionResult<Person>> PostPerson(Person person)
  {
```

Now I want to add a picture of each user, and i don't know how it's gonna be the objet in angular, should i add a property  imageProfile as File which i'm not sure if it's possible , or it should be a string of the uploaded file.

```
export class person {
    idPerson:number=0;
    fname : string ="" ;
    lname : string  ="";
    password : string ="";
    idCategory? :number;
    nameCategory:string="";
    imageProfile : 
}
```

Comment: if you want to upload it together with a post response convert the blob from the file into base64 string. Not saying that is the best solution. but its one of the easiest way to do it.

Comment: I saw other example that user formdata to send the file object, what do you think about it  https://code-maze.com/upload-files-dot-net-core-angular/

Comment: that would work it would require you wait for the file to be uploaded before submitting the person, which is probably fine.

Answer (score 0):

That's very good info from Codemaze, as always. The remark from Lavstsen is not correct, there's no need for a separate call.

For example, you could have a form linked to the structure of the person-type:

```
initializeForm() {
    this.personForm = this.form.group({
        fname: [''],
    })
}
```

In your onSubmit-method, you seize the date from your form and put in a dto, in this example through a getPersonDto-method

```
private getPersonDto(): PersonDto {
    let dto = new PersonDto();
    dto.fname = this.imageForm.controls.fname.value;
    return dto;
}
```

and next you can solve it like this:

```
const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('Imagefile', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
    formData.append('fname', personDto.fname); // needs to be strings => toString()
    this.personApiClient.uploadImageFile(this.personId, formData)
        .subscribe((res: any) => {
            this.uploadOrDeleteResults = res;
            this.showToastrMessageSuccess("PAGES.COMMON.TOASTR.TITLE.SUCCESSFULCREATE", "PAGES.COMMON.TOASTR.MESSAGE.SUCCESSFULCREATE");
        },
            (error) => {
                this.crudHasErrors = true;
                this.errorHttpErrorResponse = error;
                this.errors = this.errorHttpErrorResponse.error;
            },
```

you don't need the dto-step as such, but if you structurally always use dto's in your application, it would make more sense

Take care and good luck

Answer (score 0):

I have another workaround but this will only work for very small files where you don't need upload percentage to show on UI.

I have my controller like this:

```
    [HttpPost("/api/sign-up")]
    public void SaveUser([FromForm] UserModel info) 
    {
        _logger.LogDebug(null, "Hello", info); // Just to see contents of info object in debugger
    }
```

and make your model like this:

```
public class UserModel
{
    [FromForm(Name = "avatar")]
    public IFormFile Avatar { get; set; }

    [FromForm(Name = "email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

}
```